# Data Frame in R use like SQL, possibly using sqldf()

Tags: sql, json, r, statistics

I'm not at all familiar with R. I have basic competency using MATLAB which I do like a lot.

My current task involves gathering nice statistical data and analyzing it. I have scraped my data from JSON into a data frame by using fromJSON in the RJSONIO lib. Then I removed `NULL` values with

```
  Stats <- lapply(Stats, function(x) {
  x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
  unlist(x)})
```

then called

`DF<-do.call("rbind", Stats)` to get the JSON values packed into a data frame. This left me with full atomic vectors, so this was cleaned up using

`DF<-as.data.frame(DF)`

Now I'm left with a DF where I'd like to be able to perform *query-esque* (SQL) calculations, ie.. My research has led me to a library called sqldf, but it seems to have many dependencies that I can't get running on my machine. Still looking for a solution.

```
List all people who are on team "NYI"
```

or

`Find total number of goals for team`

or even most helpful

```
Lookup data by name or other key value
```

Sample data frame:

`_              Name Team Opponent
167    Matt Carkner  NYI      PHI
168   Keith Ballard  MIN      FLA
169 Willie Mitchell  FLA      MIN
170     Rob Scuderi  PIT      BOS
171    Nate Prosser  MIN      FLA
172    Nick Schultz  PHI      NYI`

Comment: Believe posting a sample data and desired output would help the folks here to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Suggest `data.table` package.

```
# toy data
# I presume your first column of data is number of "goals"
df <- structure(list(Goals = 167:172, Name = structure(c(2L, 1L, 6L, 
5L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Keith Ballard", "Matt Carkner", "Nate Prosser", 
"Nick Schultz", "Rob Scuderi", "Willie Mitchell"), class = "factor"), 
    Team = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("FLA", 
    "MIN", "NYI", "PHI", "PIT"), class = "factor"), Opponent = structure(c(5L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("BOS", "FLA", "MIN", "NYI", 
    "PHI"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Goals", "Name", "Team", 
"Opponent"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x001924a0>, index = structure(integer(0), "`__Team`" = c(3L, 
2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 4L)))
```

illustrations on a few operations

```
setDT(df)  # convert data frame to data.table
df[Team == "NYI",]   # there's faster approach by first keying the concerned column
# you get
   Goals         Name Team Opponent
1:   167 Matt Carkner  NYI      PHI

df[,list(ttl_goals = sum(Goals)), by=Name]  # to get total goals per player
# you get
              Name ttl_goals
1:    Matt Carkner       167
2:   Keith Ballard       168
3: Willie Mitchell       169
4:     Rob Scuderi       170
5:    Nate Prosser       171
6:    Nick Schultz       172
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLDF turned out to be the **PERFECT** solution to my type of question.

I simply installed the package from the R console

```
install.packages("sqldf")
```

Since I'm running on an Apple system, some Xcode dependencies needed installing, but Software Update took care of that for me autonomously.

Then I simply used the

```
library(sqldf)
```

command to begin running SQL queries on my data frames.

Use is very much so similar to standard SQL, return is new DF with requested attributes. Wrapped up in a view tag makes it a perfect tool now.

`View(sqldf("SELECT * from skaters WHERE Team='PHI'"))`